# Why doesn't it match

Tags: scheme

I'm confused about the macro pattern of scheme

```
(define-syntax test

  (syntax-rules ()

    ((_ (head ... (x y) . tail))

     (syntax-error

      'tail

      "tail is"))

    ((_ any ...)

     (syntax-error "fallback"))))
```

why `(test (1 7 (2 4) 34))` dosen't match the first rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax rules pattern matcher is greedy and does not backtrack on the same pattern. `head ...` matches `(1 7 (2 4))`, but `34` does not match `(x y)` and therefor it fails. If you expect only one element after you can do this:

```
(define-syntax test
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (head ... (x y) last-element))
     (syntax-error
      'last-element
      "last element is"))
    ((_ any ...)
     (syntax-error "fallback"))))
```

If you are trying to get zero or more elements after the last list of two then you need to massage it a bit is you still want to use `syntax-rules`:

```
(define-syntax test
  (syntax-rules (build)
    ((_ build m post (x y) . tail)
     (test build #t () . tail))
    ((_ build m (post ...) any . tail)
     (test build m (post ... any) . tail))
    ((_ build #t post)
     (syntax-error
      'post
      "tail is"))
    ((_ (head ...))
     (test build #f () head ...))
    ((_ any ...)
     (syntax-error "fallback"))))
```

A symbol in the patytern matches anything. This is why the pattern for `(x y)` needs to go first since `any` does match `(2 4)` as well. eg. for `(test (1 7 (2 4) 34 (3 4 5)))` the post will be `(34 (3 4 5))` since neither of those elements matches `(x y)` but both matches `any`.

Note that `syntax-error` is not part of Scheme.

Answer (score 3):

A list is a pair whose `cdr` is `()` so your input is considered like this:

```lisp
(1 7 (2 4) 34 . ())
```

So the `(2 4)` is consumed by the `head` and `34` doesn't match with `(x y)`.

Comment: But wait, Are you missing something? A list should be a pair whose `cdr` is `()` or another list, right? So the input can be:`(1 7 (2 4) . (34))`. Right?

Comment: Short answer, no. `(1 7 (2 4) . (34))` ends up the same input as the above. You may want to observe what'd be the result of `(cons 1 '(2))`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: So why can't `tail` match the `(34)`